# Moving Calendar Events around Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a series of Google Calendars I am subscribed to. In my main Spreadsheet that I do most of my work out of, I have a launch page that I want to have the events pulled for today and tomorrow from each Calendar.

The data is pulled from Google Calendar and put into a hidden sheet called Under The Hood. I then use the following query to try and pull the ones that are A) relevant and B) Happening today (or tomorrow, two different queries).

Today's Events

```
=QUERY('Under The Hood'!M4:O13, "select M, N where M contains 'P/U' or M contains 'D/O' and toDate(O) contains 'toDate(TODAY())'",0)
```

Tomorrow's Events

```
=QUERY('Under The Hood'!M4:O13, "select M, N where M contains 'P/U' or M contains 'D/O' and O contains date'" & TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

Both of these queries give me the same partial list of the events from tomorrow and the day after tomorrow.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 I had to make a copy and delete some identifiable information, but here is a very truncated version of the spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jxmi9T6E07sfCZ6iwb7bQ9p6oRiuxF5j7CpoaUIFYe0/

The launch page cells F4 and I4 are where the queries in question are located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula should be:

```
=QUERY('Under The Hood'!M4:O, 
 "select M,N 
  where M matches '.*P/U.*|.*D/O.*' 
    and O contains date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+1, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Glorious. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

### Solution

Your logic statement right now is this:

```
M contains 'P/U' or (M contains 'D/O' and O contains date'" & TEXT(TODAY()+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"')
```

*(Explicit parenthesis are inserted)*

This means that it will return true by just checking that M contains 'P/U'.

You should formulate your logic statement in a way that will check:

```
M = 'P/U' and O = 'date you want' or M = 'D/O' and O = 'date you want'
```

To do this just wrap the logical statements on the M columns inside the parenthesis as recommended by the documentation:

> You can join multiple conditions using the logical operators and, or, and not. Parentheses can be used to define explicit precedence.

```
=QUERY('Under The Hood'!M4:O13, "select M, N where (M contains 'P/U' or M contains 'D/O') and O contains date '"& TEXT(TODAY(), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",0)
```

### Reference

[Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still fairly green when it comes to coding, so I miss the easy stuff quite often. This solved it quite easily!